# wrong page numbering in the bibliography using fncychap

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, hyperref, fncychap

When I use the `hyperref` and the `fncychap` package, the bibliography in the ToC gives an incorrect link. When I click on references in the summary it does not go to page bibliography. How do I fix?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{bredon} BREDON, G.E.: {\sl Topology and geometry.} Springer: Verlag, 1995.

\bibitem{hygino} DOMINGUES, Hygino H. {\sl Espaços métricos e introdução à topologia.} São Paulo: Atual, 1982.

\bibitem{kuhlkamp} KUHLKAMP, Nilo. {\sl Introdução à topologia geral.} Editora da UFSC: Florianópolis, 2002.

\bibitem{elon} LIMA, Elon Lages. {\sl Elementos de Topologia Geral.} Rio de Janeiro: IMPA, 1976.

\bibitem{lima} LIMA, Elon Lages. {\sl Espaços Métricos}. 3ª ed. Rio de Janeiro: IMPA, 2005.

\bibitem{lipschutz} LIPSCHUTZ, S. {\sl Topologia geral.} Ed. McGraw-Hill do Brasil Ltda: Rio de Janeiro, 1971.

\bibitem{munkres} MUNKRES,J.R.: \sl {Topology: A first course.} Prentice Hall: New Jersey, 1975.

\end{thebibliography}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Refer\^encias Bibliogr\'aficas}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The load order of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`fncychap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fncychap) is important. See [`fncychap` and `hyperref` messes up page references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77886/5764).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be fixed with \phantomsection

```
...
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\phantomsection
...
```