# fncychap and hyperref messes up page references

Tags: hyperref, fncychap

When using `fncychap` and `hyperref` together, the page number for references to the appendices are off.  The Appendix A reference links to the first chapter, appendix B links to the second chapter, etc...

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One} \label{one}
This refers to the page for chapter 1: \autoref{appendix}.
The table of contents is also off.

\appendix
\chapter{Two} \label{appendix}
This is the appendix

\end{document}
```

This creates a document where the references in the table of contents link appendix A to the wrong page number (page 2 instead of page 3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the ordering of the packages.  `fncychap` must come **before** `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
```

will fix the references.

Comment: I'd add more: `fancychap` should not appear at all; but I'm biased. `;-)`